# Individual page for videos AllVideos plugin in Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla, youtube

I use Joomla for making my site and a plugin called [AllVideos](https://www.joomlaworks.net/support/docs/allvideos) for making a Video Gallery inside it. But here is a problem, AllVideos created a gallery and individual page for each videos.

The problem is that, I am unable to customize that individual page. In gallery I have title of videos, a youtube iframe and description for each and every video. But in detail page it only show me description, neither title of video nor youtube iframe tag.

I am unable to find usefully thread on lots of communities yet.

**Documentation: https://www.joomlaworks.net/support/docs/allvideos**

Comment: This sounds like a niche plugin that broadly readers may not be familiar with. Can you point us to the documentation, so that readers may see whether it allows the customisation you want? Or perhaps you can show how you have implemented it, in case Joomla itself permits the customisation you want?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Here is complete documentation https://www.joomlaworks.net/support/docs/allvideos 
and sorry for adding "urgent" actually I want to figure out this problem as soon as possible that's why i type "urgent"